# How do I wait in a Delphi console application until any key is pressed?

Tags: windows, delphi, keyboard

In a console application, what code should appear after

```
WriteLn('Hit any key to continue...');
```

to wait until any key is pressed?

---

Target platform: Windows

Comment: Does it need to be any key? I typically just do a `Writeln('Press Return to continue.); Readln;`

Comment: Yes, any key. This is the difficult part of the question :)

Comment: Don't you just do Read?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan read does not wait for input

Comment: Maybe this? https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.OnKeyPress

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk OnKeyPress can only be used in GUI applications, not in console applications

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the most important Win32 functions is [`WaitForSingleObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitforsingleobject). Indeed, you almost always rely on this function and/or its relatives when you write anything but a very simple single-threaded application.

Typically, you wait on events, mutexes, processes etc., but you can also wait on console input:

```pascal
program Project4;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Windows, SysUtils;

begin
  Writeln('Press any key to continue.');
  FlushConsoleInputBuffer(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE));
  WaitForSingleObject(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), INFINITE);
  Writeln('Thank you for pressing that key.');
  Sleep(1000);
end.
```

Please note that this really waits for *any* console input, not only keyboard events. It also responds to mouse events, window resizing events, etc.

So, you may want to investigate the kind of event using the [`ReadConsoleInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleinput) function.

I'd try something like this:

```pascal
begin
  Writeln('Press any key to continue.');
  FlushConsoleInputBuffer(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE));
  var ci := Default(TInputRecord);
  var n: Cardinal;
  while ReadConsoleInput(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), ci, 1, n) and (ci.EventType <> KEY_EVENT) do;
  Writeln('Thank you for pressing that key.');
  Sleep(1000);
end.
```

Comment: An additional Flush needed, tho, or that any key will pollute subsequent input operation.

Comment: @FreeConsulting: Are you sure? Doesn't it get removed by `ReadConsoleInput`? (From the docs: "Reads data from a console input buffer and removes it from the buffer.")

Comment: ah, not in the expanded snippet.

Comment: @FreeConsulting: Oh, I see. But that one has many more severe issues, like responding to window resizing events. That was just a pedagogical stepping stop towards the final snippet.